# Error parsing case expression

Tags: haskell

I am getting this compile error:

```
Files.hs:47:17: parse error on input ‘->’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

In the following section of code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let f = case args of
        ("W":_) -> eoltoW
        --      ^  here's 47:17
        ("U":_) -> eoltoU
        _       -> fail "2 - 3 arguments required"
    case args of
        [_,i,o] -> editWith f i o
        [_,i]   -> catWith  f i
        [_]     -> fail "2 - 3 arguments required"
```

While I understand the logic could use some tidying up, I do not see where I am going wrong with case syntax. I figure it might be some weird interaction with `do` and `let`, but I can't find any clue as to how to correct it.

Note, I have ensured that I only use spaces for indentation

### Edit:

It seems that adding a single space further of indentation (as below) is sufficient to prevent the error, but I am unclear as to why.

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let f = case args of
         ("W":_) -> eoltoW
         --      ^  here's 47:17
         ("U":_) -> eoltoU
         _       -> fail "2 - 3 arguments required"
```

Comment: You need to indent the cases further than `case`.

Comment: not just further than the line that the case statement is on?

Comment: The why is "because that's the language definition."  If you want to ask why is the language defined that way, it's to avoid parse ambiguities.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Oh I mean I thought that the compiler only cared whether some block was indented with respect to another, not how much it was indented; except in the case where a block must be in the same column as a word on the previous line; but that doesn't seem to be the case here. I understand every language choice has a reason, I simply ask how the distinction in this case fits into that. If you have a link, I'd be happy to read up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in [2.7](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) and [10.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3). Basically, the rule for `let …` in a `do` block* is that all bindings have to be indented the same way:

```
let a = …
    b = …
    c = …
```

Furthermore, the "…" have to be *more* indented than the layout list. For example, the following is a syntax error:

```
let a =
    10
in a
```

In order to create a new layout-list, we need to indent it further (see note 1 in section 10.3), which is why

```
let a =
     10
in a
```

is completely fine. The same holds for your `case`. All of the cases have to be further indented than `f` due to the off-side rule.

<sup>* that rule actually holds** for more, i.e. for `let`, `where`, `do` and `of`.</sup>
<sup>** well, as long as you don't introduce additional braces</sup>